# How to authenticate user with JWT and HttpOnly cookies

Tags: python, django, reactjs, cookies

I'm currently developing a Django-React web app and using [django-rest-framework-simplejwt](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) and [dj-rest-auth](https://github.com/jazzband/dj-rest-auth) for authentication.

At first I was storing JWT in frontend cookies ([js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)) and sending tokens in the headers to get access for restricted endpoints. Since local client cookies are not HttpOnly and after some research I found out that it was not a safe method to store it on the frontend. So I decided not to store them in the client cookies.

It seems like best solution to use HttpOnly cookies, in django settings I declared cookie name as `JWT_AUTH_COOKIE = 'myHttpOnlyCookie'`, so when I make a request from client with username and password to log-in server responses with the cookie that has the access_token.

[image: server response after a user logs in]

For the login part, I didn't write any code since dj-rest-auth handles it well so I use their standard loginserializer and view.(https://github.com/jazzband/dj-rest-auth/blob/master/dj_rest_auth/serializers.py). Well maybe I should modify it.

However the problem is I can't add the token in the header of client requests since I'm not storing the token on the client and it is HttpOnly. Well I really don't know how to authenticate the user if I can't send the token in requests.

Answer (score 0):

1. Once you make a login request to the server, tokens are added to httponly cookie by default. On consecutive requests cookies are sent by default.
2. Axios request for login.

   ```
   axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login/',
           {'email':'test_email', 'password':'test_password'},
           {withCredentials:true},
           {headers:{
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Accept': 'application/json'
           }}
       )
   ```
3. "withCredentials" must be always set to "true", this will ensure cookies are added to the every request. Once you login, tokens are stored in httponly coolie. For next requests , refer below pseudo code.

   ```
   const axiosGetReqConfig = {baseURL: '', withCredentials:true, headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json, 'Accept':'application/json'}}

   axiosGetReqConfig.get('test/').then(resp => {console.log(resp)}).catch(err => {console.log(err)})

   axiosGetReqConfig.interceptors.response.use(
       // If request is succesfull, return response.
       (response) => {return response},
       // If error occured, refresh token and try again.
       (error) => {
           const originalRequest = error.config;
           console.log(originalRequest)
           // Make a call to refresh token and get new access token.
           axios('http://localhost:8080/api/auth/token/refresh/', {
               method:'post',
               withCredentials: true
           }).then(resp => {
               console.log(resp);
           }).catch(err => {
               // push user to login page.
               console.log(err)
           })
           // Return original request.
           return axios.request(originalRequest)

           return Promise.reject(error)
       }
   )
   ```
4. In the above code, I am creating config object using some basic details and implementing interceptors to refresh token if, access token is expired. If refresh token is expired, user will be re-directed to login page.
5. Main part with including httponly cookie is the variant that we use in making axios request and "withCredentials". There is an open issue with JWT. Since dj-rest-auth uses JWT, if you need to refresh token, you have to implement middleware in django. Refer below link to implement middleware and add that middleware to settings.
   https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/issues/97#issuecomment-739942573